# Python Tkinter GUI User Login Accepting any Username with Correct Password

Tags: python, user-interface, authentication, tkinter

Alright so I must be missing something silly or obvious here but I have created this method to check for a username and password inside of my GUI and it just does some weird things. I can type in any username but as long as the password is correct, it will accept it. I have looked at the other similar questions but haven't seen an answer that accounts for my issue. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

```
    def correct_login(text):
        stored_user = user_entry.get()
        if stored_user == "admin" or "ADMIN":
            stored_pass = pass_entry.get()
            if stored_pass == "password":
                user_entry.delete(0, 'end')
                pass_entry.delete(0, 'end')
                pass_win.destroy()
            else:
                user_entry.delete(0, 'end')
                pass_entry.delete(0, 'end')
                mb.showwarning("Incorrect Credentials", "The username or password you have entered are incorrect.")
        else:
            user_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            pass_entry.delete(0, 'end')
            mb.showwarning("Incorrect Credentials", "The username or password you have entered are incorrect.")

    pass_win.bind('<Return>',correct_login)

    user_label = tk.Label(pass_win, text="Username", font=("Helvetica", 16))
    user_entry = tk.Entry(pass_win)
    pass_label = tk.Label(pass_win, text="Password", font=("Helvetica", 16))
    pass_entry = tk.Entry(pass_win, show="*")

    user_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="E", padx=20, pady=10)
    user_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=10)
    pass_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="E", padx=20, pady=10)
    pass_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W", padx=20, pady=10)

    user_entry.focus_force()

    submit_button = tk.Button(pass_win, text="Submit", command=correct_login)
    submit_button.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=("N", "S", "E", "W"), padx=20, columnspan=2)
    quit_button = tk.Button(pass_win, text="Quit", command=pass_win.destroy)
    quit_button.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=("N", "S", "E", "W"), padx=20, columnspan=2)

    user_entry.delete(0)
    user_entry.insert(0, "")

    pass_entry.delete(0)
    pass_entry.insert(0, "")
```

Comment: `if stored_user == "admin" or "ADMIN"` doesn't do what you think. You could do `if stored_user in ("admin", "ADMIN")` or `if stored_user.lower() == "admin"`

Comment: You must replace the if stored_user == "admin" or "ADMIN": with if stored_user == "admin" or  stored_user=="ADMIN":

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check needs to be:

```
if stored_user == "admin" or stored_user == "ADMIN":
```

[More info here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/wiki/faq#wiki_variable_is_one_of_two_choices.3F).